# Error using boot.ci function in R "estimated adjustment 'w' is infinite"

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

While calculating bootstrap confidence intervals for means for some data using the boot.ci command, I get the an error. In the same dataset, it is working for some data and not for others.

```
my.mean = function(x, indices) {
return( mean( x[indices] ) ) }
pakkeSTdependents.boot = boot(pakkeST$B4..Dependents, my.mean, 10000)
boot.ci(pakkeSTdependents.boot, conf=0.95)

my.mean = function(x, indices) {
return( mean( x[indices] ) ) }
pakkenonSTdependents.boot = boot(pakkenonST$B4..Dependents, my.mean, 10000)
boot.ci(pakkenonSTdependents.boot, conf=0.95)

my.mean = function(x, indices) {
+return( mean( x[indices] ) ) }

pakkeSTdependents.boot = boot(pakkeST$B4..Dependents, my.mean, 10000)
boot.ci(pakkeSTdependents.boot, conf=0.95)
```

I get the following output

```
Error in bca.ci(boot.out, conf, index[1L], L = L, t = t.o, t0 = t0.o,:
estimated adjustment 'w' is infinite
In addition: Warning message:
In boot.ci(pakkeSTdependents.boot, conf = 0.95) :
bootstrap variances needed for studentized intervals

my.mean = function(x, indices) {
+   return( mean( x[indices] ) ) }

pakkenonSTdependents.boot =boot(pakkenonST$B4..Dependents,my.mean,10000)
boot.ci(pakkenonSTdependents.boot, conf=0.95)

BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 10000 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = pakkenonSTdependents.boot, conf = 0.95)

Intervals : 
Level      Normal              Basic         
95%   ( 2.558,  4.231 )   ( 2.600,  4.200 )  

Level     Percentile            BCa          
95%   ( 2.6,  4.2 )   ( 2.4,  4.1 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale`
```

Comment: It looks like you have some stray `+` signs in there.  This question is hard to read, can you please isolate the one that is failing, show that with  results and then show one that is working with results.  Also without data it's impossible to know.   From the message about variance maybe you have no variation in your data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I could have been clearer in my question. I figured this was happening either because of less variance in data (as you pointed out), but also where I had not taken care of NA values in data in some instances.