# Error computing bootstrapped confidence interval using BCa method ('w' is infinite)

Tags: r, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to compute bootstrapped CIs using the BCa method for my Kendall's W estimate but I get the following error message:

```
Error in bca.ci(boot.out, conf, index[1L], L = L, t = t.o, t0 = t0.o,  : 
  estimated adjustment 'w' is infinite
```

My actual dataset is 4908 rows. All the other methods (norm, perc, etc.) work on this dataset and I have no missing values. I have also tried with 10,000 replications with no luck. A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896333/error-using-boot-ci-function-in-r-estimated-adjustment-w-is-infinite) but no answers were posted unfortunately. I wonder if anyone had any idea what is wrong?

Here is a test dataset with my codes:

```
library(rcompanion)

testdata = structure(list(var1 = structure(c(3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 
                                             0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                                             0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), label = "Variable 1", class = c("labelled", "numeric")), 
                          var2 = structure(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 
                                             1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                             1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), label = "Variable 2", class = c("labelled","numeric"))), 
                   row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

testci = rcompanion::kendallW(testdata, correct = TRUE, ci=TRUE, conf=0.95, type="bca", R=1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a very helpful answer, but the function simply passes the information to the `bootci()` function in the `boot` package.  I don't have any insights as to why e.g. `perc` would work in a situation and `bca` wouldn't, except that in my experience also `bca` fails in some situations.